# margins specified in dp are NOT the same relative size on different screens

Tags: android, user-interface, scaling, imagebutton

UPDATE: I figured out my problem. I had defined separate drawable resources for different resolutions, but I was not aware that I had to create different layouts for different screen sizes. I guess I should have read the "Supporting Multiple Screens" page more fully. Anyone else with this problem, read the ENTIRE page:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers

I was under the impression that the purpose of using the dp unit was to make spacing the same on different screen sizes, but I have an ImageButton which has width, height, left, and top margins all defined with dp units, and when I cycle through different screen sizes on the emulator, the button is not positioned in the same relative place.

My ImageButton is defined in the xml file as so:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/routesButton"
    android:layout_height="33dip"
android:layout_width="90dip"
    android:src="@drawable/route_button"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
    android:layout_marginTop="280dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" />
```

I'm thinking it might have something to do with ImageButton because other views with margins set in dp are adjusting properly. I'd greatly appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: You forgot to add the layout XML. ;-)

Comment: Oops lol. Forgot to hit enter after the "so:" It's up now.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem. I had defined separate drawable resources for different resolutions, but I was not aware that I had to create different layouts for different screen sizes. I guess I should have read the "Supporting Multiple Screens" page more fully. Anyone else with this problem, read the ENTIRE page:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers

Comment: I have been stuck on it for quite some time now. Are you sure that we still need to create different layout, though I have created different drawables, yet facing the same issue that you had faced? Would Android OS not scale them as per the different layout? Please help.